# Automatically resize windows?

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to make a pop-up window automatically resize to fit all the text and images contained in a page?

Comment: What happens if the page content is larger than the screen?

Comment: @Oded Good point.You can assume it never is. I know it never will be in the case I want to use it.

Comment: Why not size it to the maximum size you know of? Or, if you know the sizes in advance, build it into the popup script?

Comment: There's some JQuery that'd adjust the sizes, I don't want to set it too large and leave blank space.

Comment: people tend to not like it when a webpage resizes itself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work in chrome. You might need to tweak it for IE. It's all plain javascript, except for the $().ready, which you could replace with whatever load handler you want.

It assumes you place the contents of your popup in a div with display set to inline-block. You may have to add a little bit more offset if you have padding or margins.

`<div id="content" style="display: inline-block">...`

```
$().ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var heightOffset = window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight;
        var widthOffset = window.outerWidth - window.innerWidth;
        var height = document.getElementById("content").clientHeight + heightOffset;
        var width = document.getElementById("content").clientWidth + widthOffset;
        window.resizeTo(width, height);
    }, 100);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

using jQuery:

```
window.resizeTo($(document.body).width(), $(document.body).height());
```

But this will most likely not work in most browsers (does not work in chrome for example) as it is mostly misused. More info on
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_resizeto.asp